# PHP isn’t querying WordPress database

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

I’ve got a WordPress page with an HTML submit button that uses a post method to call a PHP file.  The PHP file reads:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   echo "Hi";
   global $wpdb;
   $result = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT EmailAdrs FROM atblNewsletter');
   echo $result;
  }?>
```

‘Hi’ appears but nothing else. I’ve checked the table and field name are correct. Any ideas please?

Comment: try `$results = $wpdb->get_results`

Comment: Thank you but it's behaving the same.

Comment: You can not echo arrays! Use print_r or var_dump to inspect the content.

Comment: I changed the echo line to echo var_dump($result) but it's behaving the same

Comment: Maybe WordPress blocks all database queries unless I pay for premium plan?

Comment: If you copy-paste that query into an SQL client do you get any results?  Have you checked your web server and PHP logs?

Comment: Is the file that has this code managed by WordPress, or is it just a regular PHP file?

Comment: @Chris not sure, I created temp.php and saved it in the public_html folder

Comment: @Don't Panic I get a result (of one row) when I run it in a shortcode directly on a page. Not sure how to check web server and PHP logs, I'm very new to WordPress.

Comment: If you have a page such as `temp.php`, and you access that page via a URL such as `https://example.com/something/temp.php`, it is almost certainly not a WordPress-controlled page, and as such _WordPress does not exist_ at that point. If this is the case, my guess is that you don't have error reporting enabled, otherwise you'd see the message "Call to a member function get_var() on null"

Comment: If I'm correct, and this is a custom PHP page not associated with WordPress, there are ways to make this work still. By far, the easiest is probably creating a [custom WordPress template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/). If you do it slug-based, you don't have to worry about the WP backend (unless someone changes the slug). You could also make it a selectable template. Alternatively, there's ways to use shortcode, rewrites, redirects and template loaders, with various pros and cons and levels of complexity.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much, you were right about error reporting, I found out how to turn that on and saw that there had been a 'Call to a member function get_results() on null' error. Once I added 'require_once('wp-config.php');' immediately before 'global $wpdb;' this disappeared and the query result appeared via the echo line.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).